# Uploading documents from iManage into SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, imanage

I have a requirement from my client to upload documents from iManage/FileSite into SharePoint 2010. When they try to upload documents into the document library they would also like to have an option to get the documents from iManage, other than from the filesystem. Please let me know if there is any easy solution to achieve this. Custom coding is also fine with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SPSite Class's Files.Add to upload your file from your alternate source.

There's a complete [walkthrough of uploading a local file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the quick reply. I am looking for a solution where user should have the ability to select the file from Imanage database directly instaed of downloading the file to local machine. IS this possible?

Comment: If Imanage includes a web service, an API or a control for that purpose, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a solution for this that uses the IWL protocol, but this would assume the user has WorkSite/DeskSite installed on their computer, and are running WorkSite 8.5 or greater.

```
iwl:dms={SERVERNAME}&lib={LIBRARY}&num={DocumentID}&ver={DocumentVersion}&command=opencmd
```

I then developed a insert link option for a user to insert a WorkSite link and they provide the link text, document number and version.

Another alternative is to upload a NRL file, but again this assumes the user has WorkSite/DeskSite installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to have a hyperlink column in the Sharepoint 2013 pointing to a document in my fileSite.

e.g link: iwl:dms=DEV85SERVER&lib=LIVE&num=25210&ver=1

e.g link description: Document test

I tried to create a hyperlink column but SharePoint didn't recognize my DMS link.

So I had to create a calculated column to make the DMS link works.

1. Create a column called "Document Link" as Single line of text.
2. Create another column called "Document Description" as Single line of text.
3. Create a third column called "Link" as a calculated column.

   3.1 insert the following formula:

```html
=IF([Document Link]="","To be inserted","<a href='"&[Document Link]&"'>"&[Document Description]&"</a>")
```

3.2 Change the type returned from this formula to "Number"
Done!

This is just an example. I hope it helps.